# Trigger an event when something changes in a class

Tags: c#, events

Is it possible to trigger some event when something changes in a given class?

E.g. I have a class that has `100` fields and one of them is being modified externally or internally. Now I want to catch this event. How to do this?

The most I wonder if there is a trick to do this quickly for really extended classes.

Comment: Is this for debugging, or is it for updating the UI? The answer will differ accordingly.

Comment: For updating UI and doing many other things

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a best practice, convert your public fields to manual properties and implement your `class` with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `interface` in order to raise a change `event`.

**EDIT:** Because you mentioned 100 fields I would suggest you to refactor your code like in this great answer: [Tools for refactoring C# public fields into properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028689/952310)

Here is an example of it:

```
private string _customerNameValue = String.Empty;
public string CustomerName
{
    get
    {
        return this._customerNameValue;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != this._customerNameValue)
        {
            this._customerNameValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Check this out: [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: Rafactor your code! Look how it easy: [Tools for refactoring C# public fields into properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028679/tools-for-refactoring-c-sharp-public-fields-into-properties)

Comment: Also check out all the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist).

Comment: @Yair: good point, refactoring makes the whole operation faster and easier:)